# How to UV unwrap an object on every frame?

Tags: materials, uv, animation-nodes

I watched Curtis Holt's Animation Nodes tutorial and started making a drone glitch effect project with it. The target is to make a plane with a simple flooring texture and displacements, some walls, and a drone model parented to a empty, The animation nodes will be taking the mesh from the plane which is the flooring and generating a target using the object output and mesh input. The floor which is just a subdivided plane has problems with materials. When I Unwrap the mesh, it works fine but when I move the empty which changes the geometry of the plane (which is what the tutorial of curtis holt is about), the mesh returns to a brown texture without the proper flooring texture so is there a way to unwrapp the mesh automatically on every frame to get the proper floor texture.

**For Refernce , Here is the tutorial link** [Animation Nodes Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C95mi7lKt8o)

**Original Plane**

[image]

**Target Plane**

[image]

My Uvs are proper, the normals are not flipped....

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial for reference?

Comment: @brockmann , added the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing here is to active "Load UVs" wich is deativated by default in the "Mesh Object Input" Node. Then you can Insert your UV Map via node as seen in the screenshot. The material itself should be copied to your target automaticly.

Animating the vertices via vector-wiggle does not change/mess up your UVs, but they will stay the same. So your applied texture should work out of the box.

(there is also a small redundancy fix in the tree from the tutorial ;) )

[image]

Comment: So , if i enable Load UVs , will the UNAsignment of UVs stop and i can sustain continuously applied texture?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. The target mesh will have the copied uvs of the source-mesh. Moving the polygons/vertices via vector-wiggle does not change their uv-entry.